# Nested recycler view, best approach of list inside list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following mock-up:

[image: picture_1]

I spent some time thinking of a solution how should I implements this. As you can see there should be a scrollable list through the dates and every date should contain a grid of the items.

I think one recycler view should be enough, I don't really know how should I achieve the grid exactly but I will figure it out, the problem I don't know and don't understand is if I should use addView dynamically in `onBindViewHolder` or there is another better way, adding them in onBindViewHolder I don't think it's ok.

Thank you, any advice from people who made something similar is more than welcome.

Comment: take a vertical recycler view with linear layout manager , then take a recycler view inside this main recyclerview with grid layout manager having 3 columns

Comment: wouldn't this also scroll the grid? I want only the main recyclerview to be scrollable

Comment: just make the height of main recyclerview wrap and also make height to wrap of inner recycler view which works as gridview , It will automatically the scrolling itself , try it and let me know